# Is there a way to get all files at once from the root directory in link format for viewing using graph api?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

To get all files from a directory, I use a query such as: `GET drives/{driveId}/root/children` .
But I would like to immediately receive all files in the format of links for viewing. Is there such a way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get links to file in the root of the current user's drive, you can use the below query

[Get] https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children?$select=id,folder,weburl

Unfortunately at the moment we can filter on folder property to get only folders but not on file property (`$filter=folder ne null` works and gives only folders in the directory but `$filter=file ne null` is not supported currently).

Being said that, you can call the above query and access "webUrl" property to get file links for id's where "folder" is not present in the response.